# Difference between normal list and dict.items()

Tags: python

```
help(difflib.get_close_matches)
Help on function get_close_matches in module difflib:

get_close_matches(word, possibilities, n=3, cutoff=0.6)
Use SequenceMatcher to return list of the best "good enough" matches.

word is a sequence for which close matches are desired (typically a
string).
possibilities is a list of sequences against which to match              
word(typically a list of strings).
```

I can use dict.keys() as the parameter "possibilities" in get_close_matches where "possibilities" expects a list. But why i can't access dict.items() as a normal list like a[0], a[1] (a is a list) ?

Comment: I think `dict.items()` might just yield an iterator. As previously named, it was `dict.iteritems()` which leads me to believe this is true and the object returns is just for iteration, not being used as a list. Sure, you could call `list()` on it to make it a list however.

Comment: So actually it return an iterator to a list not a list itself ! Thanks for your response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, `dict.items()` (and also `.keys()` and `.values()`) returns a special [dictionary view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views).  It behaves like an iterator, but isn't specifically a list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
d = {}
d['a'] = 1
d['b'] = 2

# You can pack items() into a list and then it's a "real" list    
l = list(d.items())
print(repr(l[1]))

# Or you can use itertools or otherwise use it as a plain iterator
import itertools
for p in itertools.islice(d.items(), 1, 2):
  print(repr(p))
```

Answer (score 2):

Dict.items() doesn't return a list. Instead it returns a class of dict_items. If you are interested about the keys alone use Dict.keys(). You cannot access the dictionary using index approach

Comment: What does Dict.keys() return ? I think a list. But if that's a list why can't i access it like Dict.keys()[0], Dict.keys[1] ? Thanks for your response